# How do I get all ContentEntities?

Tags: 8, entities

What I'm trying to do is

```
$entities = EntityInterface::loadMultiple();
```

That should give me all entities.

But when I call it, it gives me this

> Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface::loadMultiple()

What I need is the type and the bundles of the entities.

I don't want to get specific entities like Node, Comment, Block etc. I want to get them all.

```
$fields['node']['article'] =  <<<< I want that dynamic.
```

Something like that

```
foreach($entities as $entity) {
  $fields[$entity->getType()][$entity->bundle()] = ....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around the error about the abstract method by using `entity::loadMultiple`, but you'll get a new error, because this only works from an entity subclass.

Instead of using the static method, you would have to do this dynamically:

First get all content entity types:

```
  $entity_types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions();
  $content_entity_types = array_filter($entity_types, function ($entity_type) {
    return $entity_type instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityTypeInterface;
  });
  $content_entity_type_ids = array_keys($content_entity_types);
```

Then load all entities for each type:

```
  $entities = [];
  foreach ($content_entity_type_ids as $type) {
    $entities[$type] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($type)->loadMultiple();
  }
```